# How to read/interpret a distance matrix?

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, mean-shift

I ran some data through scikit's MeanShift clustering and had it spit out a distance matrix.

I don't know how to interpret the image or understand the value it provides.  Just looking for a clear understanding where if I had nothing other than the image, what can I determine about the data and the clustering?

[image]

Comment: looks like a handkerchief

Comment: Does not look like there is a lot of structure in the data set, does it? Did it work? Probably not too well?

Comment: No so much but that's not my concern.  I really just want to understand how to interpret it.